# Django reverse URL for app

Tags: python, django

I am using a third party app (django-sphinxdoc) in my Django project and I would like to be able to link to it in a base.html template so that it is reachable from all pages that are using base.html, but I just can't figure out how to do this. It works just fine with "Home" and "Admin" as defined below.

I have tried a number of different variants and with the below I get:

> Exception Type:   NoReverseMatch Exception Value: Reverse for
>   'doc-list' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not
>   found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []

I have a urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include('Myapp.urls', namespace='Myapp')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^docs/', include('sphinxdoc.urls', namespace='Myapp-sphinxdoc'),),
]
```

A Myapp/urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='Myapp-index'),
    url(r'^(?P<detail_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.detail, name='Myapp-detail'),
]
```

My base.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
    <html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="box">
    <h1>MYAPP</h1>
    <hr>
    <a href="{% url 'Myapp:Myapp-index' %}">Home</a>
    <a href="{% url 'admin:index' %}">Admin</a>
    <a href="{% url 'Myapp-sphinxdoc:doc-list' %}">Docs</a>
    <hr>
    {% block content %}{% endblock %}
    {% block footer %}
    <hr>
      © Copyright 2017, MG
    {% endblock %}
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

In the sphinxdoc urls.py I found the name 'doc-list' which I am trying to refer to above:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.OverviewList.as_view(), name='docs-list',),
...
```

I guess that I do not understand how to use name and namespace and any suggestions would be much appreciated.

/M

Comment: Can you share a link to the `sphinx` urls?

Comment: As per the [`django-sphinxdoc.sphinxdoc.urls`](https://github.com/yawd/django-sphinxdoc/blob/master/sphinxdoc/urls.py) there is no url named `docs-list`.

Comment: Probably forgetting `s` should be  `'Myapp-sphinxdoc:docs-list'`

Comment: Oh, yeah a typo. In the `urls.py`, however, there is no such `url`. Anyways!

Comment: Thanks for the replies! You were right there was a typo and when I added the 's' in'Myapp-sphinxdoc:docs-list' my application starts with threee links displayed 'Home', 'Admin' and 'Docs'. Previously I got the NoReverseMatch already at this stage. But, if I now press the 'Docs' link it throws a NoReverseMatch with "Reverse for 'doc-index' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'slug': 'Myapp}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []".

Comment: @nik_m following your link I agree that there is no 'docs-link', but if I look in the source on my server, ie ~/.virtualenvs/atrackdev/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sphinxdoc/urls.py then there is a first urlpattern with the name='docs-list'. Maybe we are looking at different versions?

Comment: @nik_m I think I use version 1.5.1:  $ sudo pip install django-sphinxdoc
[Downloading/unpacking django-sphinxdoc
  Downloading django_sphinxdoc-1.5.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, now it works, but I do not really understand why...
I corrected the typo that was found by nik_m and metmirr and then I added a row to my root urls.py, the third url pattern below:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include('Myapp.urls', namespace='Myapp')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^docs/', include('sphinxdoc.urls')),
    url(r'^docs/', include('sphinxdoc.urls', namespace='Myapp-sphinxdoc')),
]
```

If I remove any of the third or fourth pattern I get errors.
So, I am happy that things are working, but I would really like to understand why.

Comment: Way to go @mats! Bravo!

Comment: nik_m, metmirr, thanks for your help. I still do not see why I need that new urlpattern though.